# Program Terminates Before Reaching Essential Code

Tags: java

A little background, I saw a question on here a while back about creating a program that asks how many people are in the room, and then you 'interview' each person on their age, assign them to an age group, and then print their age group and the amount of people in that age group. I decided to take a shot at it off of needing an idea for a practice program, unfortunately the code terminates before getting the first for statement and i'm not exactly sure why. I assume it would be a syntax error but I honestly have no idea, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class UnkownProjects {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner stringInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner numInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many people are in the room?");
    int amountOfPeople = numInput.nextInt();
    int[] totalPeople = new int[amountOfPeople];
    System.out.println("Test");

    for(int index = 0; index == totalPeople.length; index++){
        System.out.println("Please enter an age for each person in the room:");
        int ageOfPerson = numInput.nextInt();
        ageOfPerson = totalPeople[index];
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
    for(int index = 0; index == totalPeople.length; index++){
        if(totalPeople[index] < 20 && totalPeople[index] > 0){
            int[] underTwenty = null;
            underTwenty[index] = totalPeople[index];
            System.out.println("Test");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I also know the spacing is a bit off but I just copy/pasted and tried to make it look pretty for you all, so don't worry. Oh and the 'println' statements were just there to check and see where the program terminates.

Output:

How many people are in the room?

(A number you would've entered here)

Test

**Ninja Edit:**

Decided that I should come back to this post and place the finished code here for anyone who comes across this question and would like to take a look at the finished product.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InterviewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            Scanner numInput = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("How many people are in the room? (Ex: 5, 10, 24)");
            int totalPeopleInRoom = numInput.nextInt();

            int[] agesOfPeopleInRoom = new int[totalPeopleInRoom];
            int youngPeople = 0, middleAged = 0, oldPeople = 0, deadPeople = 0;

            System.out.println("Please enter an age for " + totalPeopleInRoom + " people (Ex: 17, 21, 45):");

            for(int index = 0; index < agesOfPeopleInRoom.length; index++){
                int tempAgePlaceHolder = numInput.nextInt();
                agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] = tempAgePlaceHolder;

                if((index + 1) == (totalPeopleInRoom/2)){
                    System.out.println("Half way there!");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Age Group\tAmount In Group");

            for(int index = 0; index < agesOfPeopleInRoom.length; index++){
                if(agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] < 30 && agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] > 0){
                    youngPeople = youngPeople + 1;
                }
                if(agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] < 60 && agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] > 30){
                    middleAged = middleAged + 1;
                }
                if(agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] < 115 && agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] > 60){
                    oldPeople = oldPeople + 1;
                }
                else if(agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] < 0 || agesOfPeopleInRoom[index] > 115){
                    deadPeople = deadPeople + 1;
                }
                }
                System.out.println("Young People:\t" + youngPeople);
                System.out.println("Middle Aged:\t" + middleAged);
                System.out.println("Old People:\t" + oldPeople);
                System.out.println("Dead People:\t" + deadPeople);
                System.out.print("Total People:\t");
                System.err.println(totalPeopleInRoom);

        }catch(InputMismatchException inputException){
            System.err.println("[ERROR] Wrong type of input used: " + inputException);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad for loop: `for(int index = 0; index == totalPeople.length; index++)`

Instead do: `for(int index = 0; index < totalPeople.length; index++)`

Let's break the for loop down:

- The first part of the loop, `int index = 0` is the initial condition. It tells the loop what the index should be set to when the loop starts.
- The 2nd item in the for loop, in your loop you have `index == totalPeople.length`, is the condition statement that tells the for loop whether to keep looping if true or to stop looping if false. Your statement will be false when the loop tries to begin, and so the loop will *never* begin. So this is where your problem is. Instead you want to tell it to continue looping as long as the index is less than the length of the array, or in Java, `index < totalPeople.length`.
- The 3rd item in the loop, here `index++`, tells the loop what to do with the index at the completion of each loop. Here you're telling it to increase by one, which is good.

Comment: Thankyou, this is actually the first time i've done something like that and now I know not to do it again xD

Answer (score 1):

`for(int index = 0; index == totalPeople.length; index++)` should be

`for(int index = 0; index < totalPeople.length; index++)`

otherwise the boolean condition is evaluated to false and hence the loop doesn't execute

You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

> The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:
>
> `for (initialization; termination;
>        increment) {
>       statement(s) }`
>
> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>    1. The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
>    2. When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
>    3. The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment
>   or decrement a value.

Comment: Thankyou, I really appreciate your help and the link you gave. Funny thing is I was actually reading that while coding this program and attempted to use an enhanced for statement but that proved a little difficult for what I was trying to accomplish. But once again, thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop condition must be `true` for it to iterate; it breaks out when it's `false`.  In your case, it's `false` right away, so it never executes.

Instead of

```
for(int index = 0; index == totalPeople.length; index++){
```

try

```
for(int index = 0; index < totalPeople.length; index++){
```

And similarly for the other `for` loop.

In the [Java tutorial on `for` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), it states this:

> When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int index = 0; index == totalPeople.length; index++){
```

The second part in the parentheses is not a stopping condition, it is a check to continue. Use:

```
 for(int index = 0; index < totalPeople.length; index++){
```

Comment: <= gets you an Index out of bounds exception, no?

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I really appreciate it. Wherever I learned how to do for loops I could've sworn it was for(starting point; end point; increment) but I guess not xD

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops are saying 
Continue doing this code while index is equal to the arrays length

What you mean to say is continue doing this code while index is less than the arrays length